# Cross join N sets of rows in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, cross-join

I have a generic "Dimension" and "DimensionMember" tables.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Dimension]
(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    [Label] [nvarchar] (255)
) 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DimensionMember]
(
[ID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
[Label] [nvarchar] (255) NOT NULL,
[DimensionID] [int] NOT NULL
) 
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DimensionMember] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_DimensionMember_DimensionID_Dimension_ID] FOREIGN KEY ([DimensionID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Dimension] ([ID])
```

These table store a large number of dimensions and dimension members.

I want to cross join dimension members from variable number of dimensions.
Example: cross join dimension members from 'Sex','Employment Type','Contract Type' dimension should produce the following combinations

```
'Male,Full time, Employee'
'Female,Full time, Employee'
'Male,Part time, Employee'
'Female,Part time, Employee'

'Male,Full time, Contractor'
'Female,Full time, Contractor'
'Male,Part time, Contractor'
'Female,Part time, Contractor'
```

The labels of the combinations should be created by concatenating labels of dimension members (as shown above).

Thank you in advance

### UPDATE

A list of dimension (e.g. 'Sex','Employment Type','Contract Type') is DYNAMIC (produced by another query at run-time).

### UPDATE 2

Fixed a small error (Dimension1 -> Dimension). Sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this pattern? ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8c512/5/0))

```
select a.label+','+b.label+','+c.label
from (select m.label from dimension1 d
  join dimensionmember m
      on m.dimensionid = d.id and d.label = 'sex') a
cross join (select m.label from dimension1 d
  join dimensionmember m 
      on m.dimensionid = d.id and d.label = 'Employment Type') b
cross join (select m.label from dimension1 d
  join dimensionmember m 
      on m.dimensionid = d.id and d.label = 'Contract Type') c
```

Granted you need to know how many subqueries to build and therefore how long the concatenation part in the SELECT needs to be.

---

**EDIT**

And here's one that does it all (updated [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8c512/12/0))

```
;with base as (
   select m.label, d.id, dense_rank() over (order by d.id) rk
     from dimension1 d
     join dimensionmember m
       on m.dimensionid = d.id
    where d.label in ('sex','Employment Type','Contract Type')
), cte as (
   select cast(label as varchar(max)) list, rk
     from base
    where rk=1
union all
   select cast(cte.list+','+base.label as varchar(max)), base.rk
     from cte
     join base on base.rk=cte.rk+1
)
   select list
     from cte
    where rk=(select max(rk) from base)
```

Comment: This confused me because you put the restriction in the join clause while I was expecting to see it in a where clause.